# Flex-grow dependent on presence of child content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two "Splits" that are using flex-grow to either be 100% if only one is present or a 50%/50% if both are present. The issue is I would like for this behavior to be dependent on the presence of content within the `div.split`s.

Through some fiddling I can either get it to do the proper expanded heights or the proper removal of content, but not both at the same time.

The content DOM structure really needs to remain the same. Maybe adding an additional wrapper would be ok if need be. I am trying to resolve this with a pure CSS solution if possible.

[JS Bin Code Snippet](https://jsbin.com/siqifomeba/edit?html,css,output)

CSS:

```
body {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
}

.split {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.content {
  /* probably something here? */
}


/*-------------- Non pertinent styles -----------------*/
.pink { text-align: center; background-color: pink; }
.blue { text-align: center; background-color: turquoise; }
  nav { background-color: steelblue; }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <section>

    <div class="split pink">
      <!-- If I remove this <h1> I would like for
           the behavior to be the same as if I
           removed this .pink.split div from the DOM -->
      <h1 class="content">A</h1>
    </div>

    <nav> Some Nav </nav>

    <div class="split blue">
      <h2 class="content">B</h2>
    </div>

  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: `flex-shrink: 0` to any `div` will hold its size.
You want that only `split` divs to grow and they should grow within the remaining space right?

Comment: @Jasam - This codepen link will help you. https://codepen.io/greatzspido/pen/NaLPdy

Comment: @AbhinavJain Yes, only the split divs would grow. Their child content would always be 100% of their parent (the splits). Though if a split has no content, than the split would be `display: none` or removed from the DOM (though css would obviously not handle that)

Comment: @HimanshuGupta The splits in that do not appear to be "removed" if they have no children. It looks to work the same as [the provided code sample](https://jsbin.com/siqifomeba/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: If it has no content, then the height will be 0, so you need not remove it from DOM, so  
`flex-shrink: 1` should solve the problem right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the JSBin demo fills the viewport, there is 2 solutions for solving this.

1. The solution to the inline code, where the `section` doesn't fill the viewport.

You should use `flex-grow: 1;`, not `flex: 1`, as with `flex: 1`, which is the same as `flex: 1 1 0`, the *flex-basis* is 0, and when, the flex items will *flex-grow* based on their content is 0, hence take equal space.

Alternatively you could use `flex: 1 1 auto`.

Src: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common

Stack snippet - with content

```css
body {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.split {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;                 /*  or "flex: 1 1 auto"  */
}


/*-------------- Non pertinent styles -----------------*/
.pink { text-align: center; background-color: pink; }
.blue { text-align: center; background-color: turquoise; }
nav { background-color: steelblue; }
```

```html
  <section>

    <div class="split pink">
      <!-- If I remove this <h1> I would like for
           the behavior to be the same as if I
           removed this .pink.split div from the DOM -->
      <h1 class="content">A</h1>
    </div>

    <nav> Some Nav </nav>

    <div class="split blue">
      <h2 class="content">B</h2>
    </div>

  </section>
```

Stack snippet - without content

```css
body {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.split {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;                 /*  or "flex: 1 1 auto"  */
}


/*-------------- Non pertinent styles -----------------*/
.pink { text-align: center; background-color: pink; }
.blue { text-align: center; background-color: turquoise; }
nav { background-color: steelblue; }
```

```html
  <section>

    <div class="split pink">
      <!-- If I remove this <h1> I would like for
           the behavior to be the same as if I
           removed this .pink.split div from the DOM -->
    </div>

    <nav> Some Nav </nav>

    <div class="split blue">
      <h2 class="content">B</h2>
    </div>

  </section>
```

---

2. The solution for the JSBin, where the `section` fill the viewport

Use the `:empty` selector, and when the `split` is empty, change it to `flex: 0`.

Stack snippet - with content

```css
body {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.split {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.split:empty {
  flex: 0;
}


/*-------------- Non pertinent styles -----------------*/
.pink { text-align: center; background-color: pink; }
.blue { text-align: center; background-color: turquoise; }
nav { background-color: steelblue; }
```

```html
<section>

    <div class="split pink">
      <!-- If I remove this <h1> I would like for
           the behavior to be the same as if I
           removed this .pink.split div from the DOM -->
      <h1 class="content">A</h1>
    </div>

    <nav> Some Nav </nav>

    <div class="split blue">
      <h2 class="content">B</h2>
    </div>

  </section>
```

Stack snippet - without content

```css
body {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.split {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.split:empty {
  flex: 0;
}


/*-------------- Non pertinent styles -----------------*/
.pink { text-align: center; background-color: pink; }
.blue { text-align: center; background-color: turquoise; }
nav { background-color: steelblue; }
```

```html
<section>

    <div class="split pink"></div>

    <nav> Some Nav </nav>

    <div class="split blue">
      <h2 class="content">B</h2>
    </div>

  </section>
```

Comment: hmm, when I run in on my machine or [on jsbin](https://jsbin.com/qeyosiduka/1/edit?html,css,output) it does not appear to work as it is with the built-in snippet viewer. Are you getting the same?

Comment: @Jadam For some reason the JSBin fills its view, the Stack snippet does not, and with the given code sample, the Stack snippet does it correct, so I posted 2 solutions, based on if the viewport is filled or not

Comment: The intent is for it to fill the view. The link to the jsbin in the question does reflect that. There was an edit (not approved by me) which copied over the jsbin to the SO snippet system. Not sure why that does not reflect how it works in both a plain html/css file or jsbin.

Comment: @Jadam My 2nd sample show a solution when `section` fill viewport

Comment: ah, I found the disconnect. It appeared to not be working because If closing tag is not on the same line (new line between tags) it was reading it as not empty and left the pink split in. Interesting/strange...

Comment: @Jadam Yes, for `:empty` to work there can't be _anything_ inside, not even a line break